# Procedural texture on moving hair particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials, hair

I have hair particles with procedural texture on it. When I animate the particles, texture does´t move with them and this looks odd.
How could I make texture move with hair particles? Is it possible?

[image: hair particles]

[image: Node setup]

Comment: The base of the hair doesn't move so why would the texture?